# jQuery 1.10.2 warning issue from Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I tried to use latest jQuery for my website and I get this warning sign and message from Firefox 24.

> Warning: Use of `getPreventDefault()` is deprecated.  Use `defaultPrevented` instead.
>
> Source File: file:///C:/wamp/www/bootstrap3/dist/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
>
> Line: 5
>
> Warning: SyntaxError: Using `//@` to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use `//#` instead
>
> Source File: file:///C:/wamp/www/bootstrap3/dist/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
>
> Line: 1

Is it fine to leave that problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is a known issue, reported for version 1.10.2 and has been resolved for the 1.11/2.1 jQuery milestone. See a proposed pull request [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1294), and the report on the bug tracker [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14282).

To fix this, just use a later version of jQuery, or change this line in `event.js` from:

```
this.isDefaultPrevented = ( src.defaultPrevented || src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ) ? returnTrue : returnFalse;
```

To this line:

```
this.isDefaultPrevented = src.defaultPrevented ? returnTrue : returnFalse;
```

**Edit:** The pull request linked above was never merged, although it did fix the problem. The issue was instead resolved by [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/4671ef15c2d62962048fd4863911146fcc085f26) commit and looks like this:

```
this.isDefaultPrevented = src.defaultPrevented || src.defaultPrevented === undefined && ( src.returnValue === false || src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ) ? returnTrue : returnFalse;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you know when version 1.11 will out? Got any road-map?

Comment: 2.0.3 is causing the same issue for me.

Comment: @willlma He said it's been resolved in 2.1, which is after 2.0.3. JQuery 1.x and 2.x are not sequential, but just with or without IE support.

Comment: Actually it doesn't solve the problem. I've disabled all extensions, opened empty html but the message still pops up **after pressing any key**. Firefox still uses getPreventDefault() somewhere internally. "Firefox/47.0"

Comment: Update. That firefox came out of the box with ubuntu 16.04. 47.0.1 installation solved problem

Answer (score 1):

jQuery version 1.11.0 is out now. You may download it here:
http://jquery.com/download/ .
It solves the warning issue on Firefox.

Comment: Confirming that the problem still there with jQuery v.1.11.1

Comment: @Dariush worked fine for me. I came about this Q&A  from a Google search and found this answer. Plus, 1.11.1 also worked, so I don't know why you and the other guy are saying it's not working.

Comment: It's just because it doesn't ;)

Comment: Likely, there are multiple causes for this warning. jQuery 1.11.x probably solved a few of them, but not all.  Perhaps browser specific.

Answer (score -1):

it resolved by replacing the latest version of js , visit jquery site and replace with the latest jquery for the listed file

```
jquery-1.10.2.js
jquery-1.10.2.min.js
jquery-1.10.2.min.map
```