# jQuery version 1.10.2 deprecated warning in Firefox

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am developing a web page and am using the 2012 theme on Wordpress. I inserted a slider (`"responsive-slider"` plugins); however, I got an error on Firefox (up-to-date) in the console saying `Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.`

I found an answer from this post: [jQuery 1.10.2 warning issue from Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372658/jquery-1-10-2-warning-issue-from-firefox), and it suggests that I have look at my jQuery file and look for this line:

```
"this.isDefaultPrevented = ( src.defaultPrevented || src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ) ? returnTrue : returnFalse;"
```

and change it to:

```
this.isDefaultPrevented = src.defaultPrevented ? returnTrue : returnFalse;
```

In my situation, I got a line like this:

```
this.isDefaultPrevented=it,e&&(e.preventDefault?e.preventDefault():e.returnValue=!1)
```

and this:

```
this.isDefaultPrevented=e.defaultPrevented||e.returnValue===!1
```

Any suggestions on how I could change those lines into the correct ones?

Comment: it is a warning not an error.... so I would suggest you to wait till the jQuery guys make appropriate changes

Comment: This warning in the console is driving me crazy, i am using 1.8.3., does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For future issues with this As Arun stated, it's a warning and not an error.  Warnings like this that are known bugs should be addressed in a future update, which this one should have been fixed in 1.11.1.  So it's best to let them sort it out for the next release.

This should have been fixed with the update, if it was mark it as answered.