# Children of posts ruby on rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parent-child

I am trying to make children of posts with rails 4. The posts is nested resources with user.
I want a button in the _form that says "add another post" and and to work with JavaScript.
The result of this is to create post and if I want to create more posts with the same post id i will press the button and brings me another form to fill.
If you have any questions please comment before you answer.

in posts controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authorize_admin!, except: [:index, :show]

    def index
         @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @posts = @user.posts
    end
    def new
        @post = Post.new
        @post.user_id = session[:user_id]
        @user = User.find_by_name(session[:user_name])
    end

    def create
         @user = User.find_by_name(session[:user_name])
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        if @post.save
        flash[:notice] = "Post has been created."
        redirect_to user_post_path(@user,@post)
        else
        flash[:alert] = "Post has not been created."
        render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @user = User.find_by_name(session[:user_name])
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if @post.update(post_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Post has been updated."
        redirect_to user_post_path(user, post)
        else
        flash[:alert] = "Post has not been updated."
        render "edit"
        end
    end
    def destroy
            @user = User.find_by_name(session[:user_name])
        @post.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Post has been destroyed."
        redirect_to '/'
    end


private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description,:prediction,:user_id)
    end

    def set_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        flash[:alert] = "The post you were looking" +
        " for could not be found."
        redirect_to '/'
    end

end
```

in view>posts>_form

```
<%= form_for [@user,@post] do |f| %>

  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %>
      prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 <h2>New Post</h2>

<p>
<%= f.label :title %><br />
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :description %><br />
<%= f.text_field :description %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :prediction %><br />
<%= f.text_field :prediction %>
</p>
<%= f.text_field :user_id %>


<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're wanting to create multiple posts, calling the forms with Javascript (and presumably Ajax)?

---

**Id**

Firstly, you can't have posts with the same `id` - `id` is a [primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key), which cannot be duplicated. If you want to have multiple posts from the same `user`, you'll use a [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to denote who created the posts

If you're creating posts per user, I'd create a `has_many` relationship on the User model like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This will allow you to allocate a `foreign_key` to the posts, associating the user to the post

---

**Ajax**

If you're loading forms with Ajax, I'd do it like this:

1. Create a form partial
2. Load form partial every time you click "New Post" (ajax)
3. Submit the form with Ajax

Problem with this is you'll only be able to submit one post at a time. Reason being Rails only sees one set of params & works to process them as required. I could be wrong here, but unless you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, you'll have to use Ajax to submit the form too:

```
//app/assets/javascripts/user.js
$("#new_post_button").on("click", function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "/posts/form", //-> your endpoint
        type: "get",
        success: function(data) { 
             $(".user_forms").append(data);
        },
        error: function(data)   { alert(data); }
    });

});

//need to give form ID (probably timestamp)
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
        url: "/posts",
        type: "post",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) { 
             alert("Post Created!");
        },
        error: function(data)   { alert(data); }
    });
});
```

There are some more things to implement, but this is where I'd start. If you want me to write some more code, let me know!

---

**Update**

CoffeeCode for you:

```
$("#new_post_button").on "click", ->
  $.ajax
    url: "/posts/form" #-> your endpoint
    type: "get"
    success: (data) ->
      $(".user_forms").append data

    error: (data) ->
      alert data



#need to give form ID (probably timestamp)
$("form").on "submit", (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $.ajax
    url: "/posts"
    type: "post"
    data: $(this).serialize()
    success: (data) ->
      alert "Post Created!"

    error: (data) ->
      alert data
```

Comment: The first part in models i already did it. What else things i must implement? Also i have put the code you wrote and says SyntaxError: reserved word "function" (in /home/kosh/bets/app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee) <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %> . I must remove the turbolinks?

Comment: You need to handle the creation of the forms & adding new forms from your button. If you can do that, you'll be able to do as you need. You should follow what I wrote

Comment: also why i have to put this on #app/assets/javascripts/user.js and not in post.js?

Comment: I just presumed you had it in `users` because you were trying to do nested forms; you can put it in `posts` if you want!

Comment: It's because you're using coffeescript! Coffee is a different syntax than standard JS, and doesn't allow you to use the `function` word, nor `var`. I would recommend just calling that file `.js` for now, or using http://js2coffee.org

Comment: Yes i found this site js2coffee.org but when i put your code there says SyntaxError: Missing }

Comment: any way i rename the file to .js and it worked now in _from what i have to put to get the that function? please update the answer code

Comment: `that function` - which function do you need?

Comment: i am on url : users/1/posts/new and there i want to have a button add another post before the submit button. And with the ajax bringing me new from in the same page. The code you posted it doesn't do that?

Comment: Yes it does - let's chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43764/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-marios)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372658/jquery-1-10-2-warning-issue-from-firefox) i found this but i cant find where is that file so i can change the line

Comment: come to chat if you can so we can finish this

Comment: Have you got a link to the chat?

Comment: [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43764/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-marios) hey @Rich come to chat if you can so we can finish it plz.