# AJAX does not import any data into the section

Tags: jquery, ajax

Simply put, i just want to change the content of the article section that has a class ".article" on herself. ".middle-main" is a main div-container box of a website in which a content appears. So, when i push the navbar buttons i want AJAX to import content from two separate locations: "/home.html" and "/about.html".

Here's the very simple code, yet it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#home").on("click", function() {
         $.ajax("/home.html", {
            success: function(response) { 
                $(".article").html(response);
            }
        });
        $(".middle-main").fadeToggle(1000);
    });
    $("#about").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax("/about.html", {
            success: function(response) { 
                $(".article").html(response);
            }
        });
        $(".middle-main").fadeToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

When I applied this solution the article section is blank, it doesn't import anything there, why?

Uploading the HTML here, its Bootstrapped:

```
<section id="navigatory">
        <section class="boom">
            <article>
                <h1>Waffles! 
                </h1>
            </article>
        </section>
        <nav  class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-2 navbar">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 navbar">
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 navbar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
         </section>


         <section id="main">
            <main class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5 middle-main">

                        <article class="article">


                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 middle-right">
                        <aside>


                        </aside>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    </div>
            </main>
        </section>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="footer">
        </div>
```

Comment: Pop open your console and watch the AJAX request, is it coming back without error?

Comment: And home.html and about.html is just a bunch of <h1> and <p> nothing else there.

Comment: My answer is : Just remove the fadeToggles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the fadeToggles! FadeToggle is making your middle-main DIV disappear...

```
$(".middle-main").fadeToggle(1000);
```

Take a look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xv3JR/)** to try it for yourself

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, sorry, but I think you didn't answered the question well... You had given no focus on real problem, the problem that prevents the code to run...

Comment: Okay, but whichever result I apply I don't get it on my PC, I honsetly don't know why, I even put "about.html" and "home.html" to every other folder where both main.js is and jquery file... Still no result, the div remains empty.

 I wanted div to appear only when i click on it and it, so middle-main is display:none in my CSS file. 

I also wanted to shuffle my content from different html elements, rather than hard codin each div with paragraph content inside my html but I think I am going to go crazy before I finally manage to...

Comment: Oh, Man, about.html and home.html must be in the root of your site, something like `http://localhost/about.html`

Comment: but they are in the root folder, straight next to the index.html yet it aint working... Ajax simply dont want to take it. Dont know the reason? Its only some <p> and <h1> in those two.

Comment: Execute your code with this panel opened to see the outputs... Is there any error? Are requests Status Code 200?

Comment: as for the console, apart from some vendor prefixes missing after the click, no JS erros involved except this: 

"SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery-1.10.2.min.js:1
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: There's an post about this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372658/jquery-1-10-2-warning-issue-from-firefox . Maybe you can update your jquery version

Comment: What browser are you using? And how about the requests Status Codes?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I finally localized my error and applied the solution, I switched to Google Chrome and it gave me more detailed console error which I didnt see in FireFox console.