# How to get rid off the warning/error "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead."?

Tags: javascript, jquery, warnings, preventdefault, jquery-1.7

I'm using **jQuery v1.7.1** in my project. I'm getting following warning/error in Firebug console:

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

in a file **jquery.js** **line no.3432**

If I click on this file name I get following code lines highlighted from jquery.js:

```
src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ) ? returnTrue : returnFalse;
```

How should I get rid off this warning/error?

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

If you want I can provide you the whole code of file **jquery.js**

Comment: Not really sure what kind of answer you're expecting.  You could either update your jquery version to a version where the deprecated functionality is no longer in use (don't know if that exists), or you could attempt to do what the warning/error message informs you, and use defaultPrevented instead of getPreventDefault()

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.10.2 warning issue from Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372658/jquery-1-10-2-warning-issue-from-firefox)