# Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead

Tags: php, jquery, css, flash, flash-builder

I am loading a flash page from PHP page. 
However, the flash content is visible in the browser only when I press 'F12'. 
till then it shows just a blank screen.

I am really not sure what exactly the issue is. 
Can anyone help me out here?

On Mozilla, I saw this warning

> "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented
>   instead."

How on earth can I prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: The warning message has nothing to do with your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372658/jquery-1-10-2-warning-issue-from-firefox  Regarding your issue, you have to post relevant code in question itself. You talk about Flash but didn't have tagged question with flash?

Comment: can you upload the code to server and send link so that we can debug and let you know the solution

Comment: // , Well done, testing your site with such detail in the Mozilla browser. I'd love to hear more!