# no idea which line of code is using getPreventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have no idea why the following warning came out and from which line of my codes:

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. 1
```

When I click the clickable "1", the following came out. But there are no codes in line 1:

[image]

My jquery versions are:

```
├── jquery@1.12.3 
├── jquery-ui@1.10.5 

<XXX>/highcharts/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

Anything wrong with **/highcharts/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js**???

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I run **grep -r "getPreventDefault" .** in my project and found the following:

```
./node_modules/pako/doc/index.html:}
./node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/domprops.json:        "getPreventDefault",
./node_modules/uglify-js/tools/domprops.json:        "getPreventDefault",
./node_modules/handlebars/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/domprops.json:        "getPreventDefault",
```

Comment: code is came from javascript first line. click on the error, that jumps to you the source, where `getPreventDefault()` is.

Comment: `But there are no codes in line 1` - you're looking at the first line of your HTML document - to the far right of the warning you should see a file name and line number, like: `myscripts.js:1` - click it.

Comment: @Adam there is no js file name after the warning.

Answer (score 0):

These are typlically just warnings informing developers that part of the code they are using is being depreciated.  The code should still work at this point, but it's warning them that at some point down the road this part of the code could stop working as you intended it.

They are giving them an example as well of what this code has changed to.

You should be safe to ignore this unless the page will physically not load, at which point you might want to investigate which library that is using this depreciated call and update it.

Comment: The issue is that I am not sure which lib I should upgrade now.

Comment: @BAE looks like this is a known issues, I did a quick search for it and returned this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372658/jquery-1-10-2-warning-issue-from-firefox

Comment: I searched my problem this morning. but my jquery version is 1.12. Please see my post for more version info.

Comment: @BAE your jquery UI is not up to date.  Try updating that and see if the problem persists.  If not, you have a library that is out of date or a brand new issue has arisen.  In either case this type of error should not interfere in any way with your page.  The only way to track it down is to update your libraries one by one until the problem goes away, or make a brand new page and add the library one by one until you see the error and then update accordingly.  But again, it's a warning and should not affect your page.

Comment: Tried jquery-ui@1.12.0-rc.2, but problem still there.